# Props value after receiving setVariables callback

Tags: relayjs

I have a question for the following scenario: 
If you use the `setVariables` method from the relay prop and change the variable in the way, that relay has to retrieve additional data from the server (for example click "load more stories" in the following playground example [relay playgorund](https://facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html#source=class%20Comment%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20%7Bcomment%7D%20%3D%20this.props%3B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20%7Bauthor%7D%20%3D%20comment%3B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20savePending%20%3D%20this.props.relay.hasOptimisticUpdate(this.props.comment)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20style%3D%7B%7Bopacity%3A%20savePending%20%3F%200.4%20%3A%20null%7D%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cimg%20src%3D%7Bauthor.avatar%7D%20width%3D%7B16%7D%20%2F%3E%20%3Cstrong%3E%7Bauthor.name%7D%3C%2Fstrong%3E%20%7Bcomment.text%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7BsavePending%20%26%26%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cimg%20src%3D%22data%3Aimage%2Fgif%3Bbase64%2CR0lGODlhEgASAPMAADMzMw0NDUtLS21tbY%2BPj6%2Bvr83Nzf7%2B%2Fvr6%2BvPz8%2Bbm5gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAKAAAAIf8LTkVUU0NBUEUyLjADAQAAACwAAAAAEgASAAAEjPDISauViZiDCkHXpAgDKADKhSSHMghGAZQtOBVDoRACwROZAIGCGwwMvQGgcFpSEAYjQbFyAWCsCQKhKBiyB5xCkUiACMbB8CkIBK4stPSZALgDAts24SUOqBwUOwQ6e20BBRUGPhoFXl52QjZhGlAaMV8DAQMVWR5jjiBkFzuJHQVgIQYbLawhrxURACH5BAAKAAAALAAAAAASABIAgwsLCy0tLWxsbFBQUJGRka6urs7Ozv7%2B%2Fvn5%2BfPz8%2Bbm5gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASL8Mh5EKIYo2JqIRmmDAKSDIMSHokkCIZBSso1FfA2EMSeEAHQxPAiEHkDYmBQwBgIAoIKoRAsO5SLoqCSIJ6KhMUT5WUGgfRAwuM1MegAYF2xbLsSXNg22RIKFgkyAAGAFAYfXAUFAwCMAI58TwZfHAIAJUACWTaLW4R2fFmLFpBYKwcGXTiiqF4hEQAh%2BQQACgAAACwAAAAAEgASAIMLCwsyMjJsbGxRUVGRkZGvr6%2FQ0ND%2B%2Fv76%2Bvr09PTp6ekAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEivDISauVqBhZyqWKICCJMChfIhGEYQyEpCBUQXiFYOsJMXgTA0uj8xlMv4rwpkgkQgPBpoJQaGiHhLCZwHaGFkFgMOYMgRRyIDA6IN4KA2qSm2NlHc1ToZ5OrB0GAFEABWoEdwZXAgAiAAQ9ATETTm4BhQUAAV0zFgiCACqXdhclBTQ2XR8TWK0UEQAh%2BQQACgAAACwAAAAAEgASAIMxMTEMDAxvb29LS0uPj4%2B4uLipqanQ0ND%2B%2Fv76%2Bvrz8%2FPn5%2BcAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEkRDJSaud5chT0p0LQSSKICyfgiTEeQjEqnjTQWh2YQiFshsUGyFDMOxsA15lYRguSCHTgUZRHJ4Sq2GhmEl0hkKhkhAMzoIveEwpn5OTRGLBoxYIqIqiEAgMDgoLdAB%2FFQR9AAWEAomMAwZUAgECJZOMeAQDMROBcgABHAAAKnkWCwGjCqKlF2UdCHcqHxZUFBEAIfkEAAoAAAAsAAAAABIAEgCDCAgIMTExbW1tT09PjY2NsLCwzs7O%2Fv7%2B%2Bvr68%2FPz5eXlAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABIjwyEmrncZIU%2B5ESkEgCUEoHkIWhaKYUlJxBmIQHFEghdBNIdaLdSIIBBpK0KBQlQQniorERGBa1lgAwA1kJ4SBQHxAbLvf8vFIKCfeCh%2FlpkikD4XtwAAf778IBFwDeUd7fj8SBAEEJQFQjHiEFAlNZgEZAQNWTRYgAQFvAwEoHmU6EiKmqxURACH5BAAKAAAALAAAAAASABIAgw0NDTIyMm5ubkxMTJGRkbCwsM3Nzf7%2B%2Fvr6%2BvPz8%2BXl5QAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASL8MhJq5XIKGnMpUlRHAhRJJ%2BChIWimBJKCYCQGEVHGOE%2BlQBAAIfLEY6eXyE4SDh7vt9KIThNcAmEVjIIAgYISklAJnC9YDFBsDavnNTRlaAK%2FwyBgEABXwsMdhIFeQMFA2sDBgQDVRQEAAQJBAFHhSGNP3UDATmMYVkXCgNNCaMbJBclcoofH1sVEQAh%2BQQACgAAACwAAAAAEgASAIMLCwstLS1tbW1RUVGSkpKvr6%2FMzMz%2B%2Fv76%2Bvr09PTl5eUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEhvDIeRCqNFNRpFJaZgBAchSFGYIIWSiopE4CQCC1YBQGYhCGCaJAGhAHOxiBRxkGAAJFApEoLEFCqoJDgU0tkkFgPLhQCAQBOgwgmydWdeeQqCuAlGSoINbZ03gUBWM6A2g6aTpnhlWGaR1WczJSOEgGAwIXUxoJCgMDdQJRIUKBOzOkTSERACH5BAAKAAAALAAAAAASABIAgwsLCzIyMmtra1FRUZGRkbCwsNDQ0P7%2B%2Fvr6%2BvX19ejo6AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASL8MhJEb1UFEmExZMBBEkCAAp4pEcAFMWYHDNFBB4BCMOOGAXDBFEIBAYxHgAIY0mIxoGiZGA6D4isgrCZKAyJ7GcwiGYpBS4XK4gKsGiCvIsobcGhwudiIBOmCQppBEJoZAJ9XIiDhRwDBAkFAooFkWsUYQgCiAaTFjUXCAqbFh1XGESFQCoXNXsUEQAh%2BQQACgAAACwAAAAAEgASAIMxMTEMDAxvb29KSkqPj4%2B4uLipqanPz8%2F%2B%2Fv76%2Bvr09PTn5%2BcAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEkBBJlGSlM%2BekiKEGcWnTAgCKGSyktHADcBgBmrwZARhdIAgBwgIomCQMJ0EB8AsgA8HNISZYKFIDaEGTuBEOI0O10kUIBmjBiFIwuMFm9KAodRu2lOvCcMgsDixcBz8EVzcFHoETBT8Cg25fIXwZBgM8jJB9B18aChIEjpsiGC0KPxUEQi1GkwgHBwprq7MIEQA7%22%20style%3D%7B%7BmarginLeft%3A%204%2C%20verticalAlign%3A%20'text-top'%7D%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AComment%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(Comment%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20comment%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Comment%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20author%20%7B%20avatar%2C%20name%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%0Aclass%20Story%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20_augmentNumCommentsToShow%20%3D%20(delta)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.props.relay.setVariables(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20numCommentsToShow%3A%20this.props.relay.variables.numCommentsToShow%20%2B%20delta%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20(readyState)%20%3D%3E%20%7Bconsole.log(this.props.comments)%7D)%3B%20%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20_handleKeyDown%20%3D%20(e)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(e.keyCode%20%3D%3D%3D%2013%20%26%26%20e.target.value%20!%3D%20'')%20%7B%20%20%2F%2F%20enter%20key%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Relay.Store.update(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20new%20AddCommentMutation(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20story%3A%20this.props.story%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20e.target.value%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20this.props.viewer%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this._augmentNumCommentsToShow(1)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20e.target.value%20%3D%20''%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20_handleMoreCommentsClick%20%3D%20(e)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20e.preventDefault()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this._augmentNumCommentsToShow(5)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20%7Bstory%7D%20%3D%20this.props%3B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20%7Bauthor%2C%20comments%7D%20%3D%20story%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cheader%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cimg%20src%3D%7Bauthor.avatar%7D%20width%3D%7B32%7D%20%2F%3E%20%3Cstrong%3E%7Bauthor.name%7D%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fheader%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3E%7Bstory.text%7D%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bcomments.pageInfo.hasPreviousPage%20%26%26%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%23%22%20onClick%3D%7Bthis._handleMoreCommentsClick%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20View%20previous%20comments%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bcomments%20%26%26%20comments.edges.map(commentEdge%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%20key%3D%7BcommentEdge.node.id%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CComment%20comment%3D%7BcommentEdge.node%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onKeyDown%3D%7Bthis._handleKeyDown%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20placeholder%3D%22Leave%20a%20comment%26hellip%3B%22%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3D%22text%22%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ful%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AStory%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(Story%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20initialVariables%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20numCommentsToShow%3A%203%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20story%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Story%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20author%20%7B%20avatar%2C%20name%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20comments(last%3A%20%24numCommentsToShow)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BComment.getFragment('comment')%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pageInfo%20%7B%20hasPreviousPage%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BAddCommentMutation.getFragment('story')%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Viewer%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20avatar%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BAddCommentMutation.getFragment('viewer')%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aclass%20StoriesApp%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20_handleLoadMoreClick%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.props.relay.setVariables(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20numStoriesToLoad%3A%20this.props.relay.variables.numStoriesToLoad%20%2B%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20(readyState)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20if(readyState.ready%20%26%26%20readyState.done)%20%7Bconsole.log(this.props.viewer.storyFeed.edges.length)%7D%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20%7BstoryFeed%7D%20%3D%20this.props.viewer%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7BstoryFeed.edges.map(edge%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%20key%3D%7Bedge.node.id%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStory%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20story%3D%7Bedge.node%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20viewer%3D%7Bthis.props.viewer%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ful%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7BstoryFeed.pageInfo.hasNextPage%20%26%26%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20onClick%3D%7Bthis._handleLoadMoreClick%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Load%20more%20stories%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0AStoriesApp%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(StoriesApp%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20initialVariables%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20numStoriesToLoad%3A%203%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Viewer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20storyFeed(first%3A%20%24numStoriesToLoad)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BStory.getFragment('story')%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pageInfo%20%7B%20hasNextPage%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BStory.getFragment('viewer')%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%09%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%0Aclass%20AddCommentMutation%20extends%20Relay.Mutation%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20fragments%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20story%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Story%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Viewer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20getCollisionKey()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%60story-%24%7Bthis.props.story.id%7D%60%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20getMutation()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Relay.QL%60mutation%7BaddComment%7D%60%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20getFatQuery()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20AddCommentPayload%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20commentEdge%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20story%20%7B%20comments%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20getConfigs()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'RANGE_ADD'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20parentName%3A%20'story'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20parentID%3A%20this.props.story.id%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20connectionName%3A%20'comments'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20edgeName%3A%20'commentEdge'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20rangeBehaviors%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20''%3A%20'append'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20getVariables()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20storyId%3A%20this.props.story.id%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20this.props.text%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20getOptimisticResponse()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20commentEdge%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20author%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20avatar%3A%20this.props.viewer.avatar%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20this.props.viewer.id%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20this.props.viewer.name%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20story%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20this.props.story.id%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20this.props.text%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20StoriesRoute%20extends%20Relay.Route%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20params%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20static%20queries%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20(Component)%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20query%20ViewerQuery%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20viewer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BComponent.getFragment('viewer')%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20static%20routeName%20%3D%20'Stories'%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AReactDOM.render(%0A%20%20%3CRelay.RootContainer%0A%20%20%20%20Component%3D%7BStoriesApp%7D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3D%7Bnew%20StoriesRoute()%7D%0A%20%20%2F%3E%2C%0A%20%20mountNode%0A)%3B)).

I would expect that after listening to the callbacks `readyState` with the values `ready = true` and `done = true` the props contain the newly fetched information. Like in the playground example, after increasing the `numStoriesToLoad` with the initial value 3 by 1 the prop `viewer.storyFeed.edges.length` is 4.

What actually happens is, that even after receiving the named callback, the props have still the old value. If this behavior is intentional, how can you chain `setVariables` calls which depend on the result of the previous call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setVariables` does not instantly update the variables.

It actually goes into a pending state and will keep returning the old variables until the props have been populated with the new data.

Checkout the `_runVariables` function in `RelayContainer` if you want to see how it is handled. it seems that when the `ReadyStateCallback` is called, the new props will not have been populated yet.

Source:
https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/0ba7d8c1cf2899ec2ac3e779ac7dedbff5f9d092/src/container/RelayContainer.js#L242-L322

Maybe you could handle that in `componentWillReceiveProps` then ?

Edit: Just found this:

https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/0ba7d8c1cf2899ec2ac3e779ac7dedbff5f9d092/docs/APIReference-Container.md#example-5

> setVariables does not immediately mutate variables, but creates a
>   pending state transition. variables will continue returning the
>   previous values until this.props has been populated with data that
>   fulfills the new variable values.